# A custom-cite command that behaves like \section

Tags: biblatex, sectioning

I have a custom cite command. I want it to behave as a `\section` command rather than having to write `\section{\customcite{}}` as I have been.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{} 

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{einstein,
        author = {Albert Einstein},
        title = {the true about tree},
        journaltitle = {Annalen der Physik},
        year = {1905},
        volume = {322},
        number = {10},
        pages = {891--921}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Cite, \customcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\customcite}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}%
      \indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printnames{labelname}%
       \space 
       \printfield{year}%
       \addcolon\space%\setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
     }%
   }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
  

\begin{document}

\section{\customcite{einstein}}

\customcite{einstein}
\end{document}
```

Edit: fixed section sizing

Comment: why not `\large` rather than `\fontsize{12}{0}` which is 12pt font (same as `\large` but specifying baselines of lines of text are 0pt apart (which it will not achieve) do you just want `\newcomand\seccite[1]{\section{\customcite{#1}}` ... `\seccite{einstein}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, something like a `\newcommand` combining `\section` and my `\customcite` which works for all my `\customcite` entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a command that calls `\section` and `\customcite`:

```
\newcommand\seccite[1]{\section{\customcite{#1}}}
```

Then use as `\seccite{einstein}`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. There's a typo and a missing bracket in the solution. The fixed one is: `\newcommand\seccite[1]{\section{\customcite{#1}}}`

Comment: @JGD updated the code